# How can I get rid of these extra entries in my lookup table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am making a simple back end to add photos to my website. Each photo can be in multiple categories and is available in multiple sizes, so I have lookup tables to join the photos, categories and sizes together.

Here is my code for populating the lookup tables:

```
foreach($request->category as $category)
   {
       $catphoto = new Category_Photo(['photo_id' => $photo->id, 'category_id' => $category]);
       $photo->categories()->save($catphoto);
   }

foreach($request->size as $size)
   {
       $photosize = new Photo_Size(['photo_id' => $photo->id, 'size_id' => $size]);
       $photo->sizes()->save($photosize);
   }
```

Here's an example of the data passed in the request:

```
"category" => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
        2 => "3"
      ]
      "size" => array:4 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
        2 => "3"
        3 => "4"
      ]
```

However, while the insertions work and the lookup tables are populated, every other inserted row contains the id of the previously inserted entry, e.g:

```
id  photo_id  category_id
85  55        1
86  55        85
87  55        2
88  55        87
89  55        3
90  55        89
```

What's happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create a new entry in your pivot table. instead you can use `attach()`

```
foreach($request->category as $category)
{
    $photo->categories()->attach($category);
    // ----- OR ---------
    $cat = Category::where('id',$category)->first();
    $photo->categories()->save($cat);
}
```

You can read more from laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)